# Derivative of Taylor's polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let's denote with $T_n(x) = f(c) + \frac{f'(c)}{1!}(x - c) + ...$ Taylor's polynomial of n-th degree.

Because $c$ can be every number in the domain of $f$, $D_f$, this polynomial is in fact in two variables, $x$ and $c$.

Now, it is obvious that $T_n(c) = f(c), \forall x \in D_f$ but I am confused about theirs derivatives. It *should be* $T_n^{(k)}(c) = f(c)^{(k)}$ because they match in points $c$ but $T_n(x)$ is a function of two variables so this isn't clear and I tried to calculate $T_1'(x)$.

Let's say $c = 5$. Then $T_1'(x) = (f(5) + \frac{f'(5)}{1!}(x - 5))'$ which is equal to $f'(5) + (f'(5))'(x - 5) + f'(5) \cdot 1$. Since $(f'(5))' = 0$ we get $T_1'(x) = 2f'(5)$.

And we do not get an equality $(f'(5) \neq 2f'(5))$. Where is a flaw in my reasoning?

EDIT: Why is $T_n^{(k)}(x) = f^{(k)}(x)$ "obvious"?

Comment: When you differentiate $f(5)$ you get $0$, not $f'(5)$.

Comment: Thanks. Complete blindness from my part. But, if we indeed differentiate Taylor's polynomial in mechanical way $k$ times and evaluate it at the point $c$ we will end up with $f^{(k)}(c)$? Also, in my textbook it writes that it is "obvious" that $T_n^{(k)}(c) = f^{(k)}(c)$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

To be precise, it's not generally true that $T_n^{(k)}(x) = f^{(k)}(x)$ since $T_n$ is only the first $n+1$ terms of the Taylor series. For example, if $f(x) = \sin (x)$ and $c=0$, then $T_1(x) = x$. In this case, $T_1'(0)=f'(0) = 1$, but clearly $T_1'(x) \neq f'(x)$ since one is $\cos(x)$ and the other is a constant. For $T_n$, we can only make the claim that the derivatives *evaluated at $c$* are equal.

As to why $T_n^{(k)}(c) = f^{(k)}(c)$, first note that it doesn't really matter that we can consider $c$ a variable, since we are differentiating with respect to $x$, and as far as the derivative wrt $x$ is concerned, $c$ is a constant. Now since it is a polynomial we can differentiate each term of $T_n$ individually. For any term with a power less than $k$, the $k$th derivative is zero, so we can ignore all terms with powers less than $k$. For terms with powers greater than $k$, the $k$th derivative will still have a factor of $(x-c)$, so choosing $x=c$ zeros out those terms. Thus we need only consider the term $\frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!}(x-c)^k$.

Since $\frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!}$ is a constant, we don't need to invoke the product rule and can focus on differentiating $(x-c)^k$. The $k$th derivative of this is just $k!$. We then multiply this by the coefficient $\frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!}$ and the $k!$ cancels out, giving $T_n^{(k)}(c) = f^{(k)}(c)$, as claimed.

Note that the claim only holds for $0\leq k\leq n$. Since $T_n$ is the Taylor polynomial of degree $n$, then for each term, the power is less than or equal to $n$. So for any $k>n$, $T_n^{(k)}(x) = 0$.